# Windows phone 8 - keep dragged object on top

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

**Scenario:**
I have several canvases on my page. Lets say that half of the canvases contains a draggable grid with a background. All the canvases and the draggable items are created in code-behind.
When I drag an object (grid) from one canvas to another it works fine. But the issue is that the dragged object does not always stay on top of all other objects.

**Question:**
How can I make the dragged object (`Grid`) stay on top of all others objects on the page?
I tried to use `Canvas.SetZindex(obj, 1000)`, but that did not work.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use additional "Operational" canvas which should be a top in the elements hierarchy.
Each time when you start drag and drop, you should translate dragging object's position from the owner's coordinate to the additional canvas coordinate and move element to the additional canvas. The reverse workflow should be implemented on end drag.

So as result dragging object always will be on top while dragging